# How to encrypt data in C++ and decrypt them back in PHP?

Tags: php, c++, security, encryption, arduino

hope the questions is not very off. I'm just getting started with encryption and writing code that is a little more secure while transferring data. We are implementing C++ on an Arduino and we are using wifi module to transmit data over HTTP to a webServer written in PHP. Since we need to keep to the client really light, we thought we use encryption rather than TCP stack or HTTPS, to make our data transfer a little more secure. We looked up some useful libraries for Arduino encryption which are mainly written in C++. So we wanted to to know how to decrypt the data back using the same algorithm but in PHP? Should we rewrite that algorithm in PHP or is there a better way? Are there any existing solutions? Is this the way to go at all?

Comment: Use https. I'm confident that there are client-side https libraries for arduino that will be far more reliable, and work far better than anything you can cobble together on your own. Because if you do have the technical skills to implement a reliable encryption solution on your own, I don't think you would be asking complete strangers for help, on stackoverflow.com

Comment: No need to be a jerk there, working on my technical skills. And stackoverflow is made for that exact purpose actually. If I use https wouldn't I need a certificate on the server side?

Comment: @SamanRajaee If you control every client (eg: Arduino devices) you can use your own CA, o simply add the self signed certificate to the chain of trust of the device.

Comment: @SamanRajaee sure, you can [create the certificates yourself](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/openssl-essentials-working-with-ssl-certificates-private-keys-and-csrs#generating-ssl-certificates), or if you want to get a proper one you can buy one or get one from free from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)

Comment: If you want encryption and can't use https then use AES.

Answer (score 1):

> So we wanted to to know how to decrypt the data back using the same algorithm but in PHP?

Assuming you have defined an encryption scheme, PHP has <s>[Mcrypt functions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php)</s> [Defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) that support symmetric chipers, [OpenSSL functions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.openssl.php) that support asymmetric chipers and [Hash functions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.hash.php).
So you just write the decryption algorithm as you would with any other language.

Many thanks to *zaph* for pointing out that *Mcrypt* is outdated.

> Should we rewrite that algorithm in PHP or is there a better way?

Since PHP is a very simple (yet subtle!) language, rewriting is usually the fastest way.
You can reuse the C++ code entirely by writing a [PHP extension](http://devzone.zend.com/1435/wrapping-c-classes-in-a-php-extension/).

Note that I'm assuming you want to write an encryption scheme, not encryption primitives.
Rewriting a block cipher, hash function or stream cipher is usually a bad idea, rewriting a custom scheme you have already implemented (see last point) in C++ is a different kind of thing.

> Are there any existing solutions?

HTTPS, more specifically [TLS](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5246.txt).

> Is this the way to go at all?

Rolling your own crypto? No.

HTTPS gives you way more that *confidentiality* (not letting know what you are sending), it gives you [sACCE](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/339.pdf) (Server-Only Authenticated and Confidential Channel Establishment).
For example if you don't take appropriate countermeasures an attacker can reply all the requests they see; a naive [block cipher mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) make the scheme easily [distinguishable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distinguishing_attack).

If your team is not confident with these terms and it has no seasoned programmers and mathematicians I suggest the use of HTTPS.
Which is not expensive as you think (It uses a stream cipher, the expensive part is the handshake and every server today support *Connection: Keep-Alive*).

---

You maybe tempted to think that you work in an environment where strong crypto is not needed, I say then no crypto is needed at all, save yourself a lot of debug.

There is no such thing as partial cryptography: either you do it correctly or you are not doing it at all.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt had many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003.. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), it is being maintained and is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! this would help a lot, will look through all of these and try to get an idea of what will be the way to go. For sure not rolling out our own crypto, we will use standard and certified libraries, but just have to find a way to make them work together.

Comment: @Margaret Bloom You might want to clarify what you mean by your answer to "Should we rewrite that algorithm". Are you suggesting re-writing a symmetric cipher such as AES in PHP, it sounds like that could be the interpretation which would be a very bad idea.

Comment: @SamanRajaee Use AES, there are libraries for C++ and you can use [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) for PHP. But there are subtleties to using encryption securely.

Comment: @zaph Thanks for pointing out Defus. About rewring algorithms, I was talking about crypto schemes, not crypto primitives. I'll clarify.